# Commons-Io Duplicate Entry Error Using Robospice and Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robospice, apache-commons-io

I've been working on the following issue for several hours, but haven't come up with a way to solve my problem.  I've tried the following fixes from Stack Overflow ([Android Studio update to 1.0 corrupts MultiDex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436641/android-studio-update-to-1-0-corrupts-multidex) and [Duplicate Zip Entry after Gradle Plugin v0.13.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059838/duplicate-zip-entry-after-gradle-plugin-v0-13-1)) but neither one of them worked.

I am getting the following error when trying to build my program:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class
```

The error seems to indicate that commons-io is being included twice in the build process

I am using Android Studio and Gradle to include multiple Robospice dependencies.  This is the dependencies section of my Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    compile'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'


    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // The Google Repository (separate from the corresponding library) can be found in the Extras category.
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknifeVersion}"
    compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.8'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.0'

    compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'){
        exclude module: 'commons-io'
        exclude group: 'commons-io'
    }

    compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.14'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'

    compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-google-http-client:1.4.14'){
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax'
    }

    compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.5'
    compile files("$buildDir/native-libs/native-libs.jar")

}
```

Using the "gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies" command  to view the project's dependency tree indicates that com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14 is dependent on the commons-io library.  Here is the relevant snippet of the project dependency tree:

```
+--- com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14
|    \--- com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14
|         +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
|              \--- commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2
```

The dependency is still listed even though I excluded commons-io from all Robospice related dependencies in the gradle build file.  I also tried changing the group name from commons-io to org.apache.commons, and that did not work either.

My project is at a standstill until I get this resolved, and I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: This answer may be helps to solve your problem [Answer_Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43862686/2599596)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known and fixed problem in Robospice, caused by an underlying Gradle 2.1 issue: https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/365. The fix is going to be released in the next version.

You can work around it by excluding `org.apache.commons:commons-io` from **all** Robospice dependencies, and include `commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2` manually. Like this:

```
// workaround (https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/365)
// remove when robospice updates to 1.4.15+
compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-ormlite:1.4.14') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. I saw that linked, but I guess I never fully implemented that solution.

Comment: @nekojsi
I Am getting  **Gradle DSL method not found: 'complie()'** when I do this.
I need urgent help please!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile about that problem.

Comment: @nekojsi I am afraid that is not my case, could you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856703/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-when-excluding-support-v4-and-or-common

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question needs a structured approach towards solving the issue which both of the above answers fail to provide.

Step 1: Find out which external library is causing duplicate zip entry. Run following command from terminal of Android Studio.
`gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies`

In my case, image picking library ('net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0') was causing the duplicate entry.

Step 2: Add code to exclude commons-io only for that library

```
compile ('net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.3.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
```

Step 3: Include updated commons-io library.
`compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'`

Now you are set to go.