# Android Gradle compiling commons-io creates duplicate in library tree

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to build and maintain an old application for work but I can't get past the build phase.  In my `app/build.gradle` file I have

```
dependencies { 
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    //some more libraries compiled as well
}
```

but get the following error when trying to execute:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class

This is almost certainly because when I compile that jar, at the top of my External Libraries tree, this is generated:

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I get it to stop so I can complete the build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple way to exclude the double classes. At first you need to find out which dependency is causing that if you know that use this code:

```
compile('com.example:some-dependency:4.2') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
```

Comment: It appears to be commons-io itself. When I leave that out, both versions disappear from the library. I'll add the exclude to its own compilation but that seems to be kind of counterintuitive...

Comment: I suspect it is the fault of this line: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` do you have a libs directory with jars?

Answer (score 13):

There is an option to fix it on gradle dependency resolution level

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') with module('commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2')
    }
}
```

Reason of the conflict is that `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2` was pushed by mistake https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421794/624706

You can see where dependency is coming from with

`gradle :main:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency commons-io`

Answer (score 5):

I know that this thread is old enough, but if someone faces this issue, the reason may be in the artifact itself.

`com.apache.commons:commons-io:XXX` has been [moved](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io) to `commons-io:commons-io:XXX` and fetching of the old artifact may produce unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that other libraries in the project have the commons-io dependency causing duplicate entries.

See if this helps - 
[Gradle Duplicate Entry: java.util.zip.ZipException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168063/gradle-duplicate-entry-java-util-zip-zipexception?rq=1)

Comment: It doesn't appear that this is the case.  I've looked at that question and ruled it out.  Looking through all my other libraries there don't seem to be any dependencies on commons_io, so I can't imagine why this is happening.