# Gradle build failed: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When trying to run the app on my nexus 7, the gradle build fails every time and gives the same error:

```
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class
```

The error seems to indicate that `CopyUtils.class` from `commons-io` is being included twice in the build process.

The full log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:android:assembleDebug]

:android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

:android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE

:android:checkDebugManifest

:android:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

:android:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE

:android:prepareDebugDependencies

:android:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE

:android:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE

:android:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE

:android:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE

:android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:android:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE

:android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE


:android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

:android:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

:android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE

:android:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

:android:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

:android:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE

:android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE

:android:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE

:android:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE

:android:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task 
':android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class

Information:BUILD FAILED

Information:Total time: 11.208 secs

Information:1 error

Information:0 warnings

Information:See complete output in console
```

Also my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.wildstang.wildrank.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.+'
    compile 'de.congrace:exp4j:0.3.+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I seem to now get

Error:(43, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1()'
Possible causes:

The project 'wildrank-android-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

My Gradle wrapper

## Wed Jul 06 21:02:27 PDT 2016

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

My new gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //IMPORTANT: 'com.android.application' not

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24 // compile sdk should always be latest
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" // Don't know if this matters

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.wildstang.wildrank.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19 //Looks like this is a new app, why are you using 19 and not 24?
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') //IMPORTANT

```
//Ignore these, I don't think they are important for you, but I needed them to get my test project to compile
// These version numbers worked for me:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'{exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io' }
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'{ exclude module: 'commons-io' }
compile 'de.congrace:exp4j:0.3.11'{ exclude module: 'commons-io' }
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'{ exclude module: 'commons-io' }
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle compiling commons-io creates duplicate in library tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185512/android-gradle-compiling-commons-io-creates-duplicate-in-library-tree)

Answer (score 22):

There is an option to fix it on gradle dependency resolution level

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') with module('commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2')
    }
}
```

Reason of the conflict is that `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2` was pushed by mistake https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421794/624706

You can see where dependency is coming from with

`gradle :main:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency commons-io`

Comment: this solve the problem, just put this code after declaring maven libraries

Answer (score 13):

Please use the below code in build.gradle file.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
}
```

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

## Edit 2:

I created a [fork](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/wildrank-android) of the project that compiles and runs on Android Studio 2.2 preview 7. You can also check out the [diff](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/wildrank-android/commit/0d014ecc0178a9c2f89e552206d48e215af8d20b) if you don't want to redownload the project.

### Edit:

Here is a `build.gradle` file that compiled for me. I've commented all the important changes:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //IMPORTANT: 'com.android.application' not 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24 // compile sdk should always be latest
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" // Don't know if this matters


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.wildstang.wildrank.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19 //Looks like this is a new app, why are you using 19 and not 24?
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs') //IMPORTANT

    //Ignore these, I don't think they are important for you, but I needed them to get my test project to compile
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'

    // These version numbers worked for me:
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1'
    compile 'de.congrace:exp4j:0.3.11'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```

Try what [Maxence Barroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38706750/4548500) said. If that doesn't work, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209752/4548500):

```
compile('com.example:some-dependency:4.2') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
```

Since I don't know what your `build.gradle` file looks like, I can't really help you, but check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27747095/4548500) too. Also, make sure you have the latest version of Gradle `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'`

Comment: My build.gradle has been added to the description

Comment: I've updated my answer with a build.gradle file that worked for me: I created a fresh project in Android Studio 2.2 and used the above build.gradle file.

Comment: Can I see the new gradle file? Also, if this is a relatively new project, maybe try just creating a new project using Android Studio. It should set everything up properly and then you can add the dependencies you need again.

Comment: Its not new. This is an open source project which I wanted to use for robotics(its allowed by the creators). Its been only having gradle problems. I'll update with the gradle file.

Comment: I got it working on my Nexus 6P: check out the edit above.

Comment: Excellent answer: thanks for sharing your build file in full - helps to see it in context.  It helped me fix my problem adding protobuf in leading to a conflict on org.apache.commons.lang, which I fixed with an   `exclude module: 'commons-lang'`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can check the gradle version. Above properties should cause of merge conflicts.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

And please try the above properties.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 compile('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') {
        exclude module: 'commons-io'
 }
```

try it..