# Error:Execution failed for task ':java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class

Tags: android, build, apk

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils.class
```

It occurs this error.

The app builds success but when I get build apk, android studio show this message

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thewell_dev.fourscompany"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
    compile 'com.estimote:sdk:0.13.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:easyvideoplayer:0.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.jrvansuita:PickImage:v2.0.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
    compile 'com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.tsengvn:Typekit:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.esafirm:RxDownloader:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.mlsdev.rximagepicker:library:1.1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.2@aar'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.8'
    compile 'io.github.jeancsanchez.photoviewslider:photoviewslider:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.gjiazhe:scrollparallaximageview:1.0'
    compile 'com.droidninja:filepicker:1.0.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

I think external libraries have 
Commons-io-1.3.2.jar
Commons-io-2.4.jar
and both have CopyUtils.class

Anyway, It can't build apk and show that message.

Please anyone help me please

Comment: There are MANY questions like this on SO. Please search first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957924/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry/39958129#39958129 see the "EDIT" section here to run the command and exclude what is needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle compiling commons-io creates duplicate in library tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185512/android-gradle-compiling-commons-io-creates-duplicate-in-library-tree)

Comment: @th3pat3l yes i think many question about it but i can't find the solution so I ask and in command line, i put ./gradlew app:dependencies not order in in or out message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one dependency you have integrated which uses Apache Commons.
just exclude them using following code in gradle.

```
compile('YOUR_DEPENDENCY') {
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
```

Comment: Same issue happened two days ago with me.
 try this with all your dependency it will definitely work.

Comment: 5 are you solved it?
try like this?
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'{
    exclude module: 'commons-io'}
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'{
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'{
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'{
    exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
  ...
like this?

Comment: yes **exclude module: 'commons-io'** helped me to resolved the issue.

Comment: Just find Dependecy tree of your gradle and find where **common-io** is used and then it like this
 `compile ('com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'){ exclude module: 'commons-io' }`

Comment: to find project dependency given link will help you.. http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-display-project-dependency/

Comment: Thank you you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this issue . You need to exclude common-io from your app build.gradle .

```
android {
    configurations{
        all*.exclude module: 'commons-io'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Techierj [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018015/602072) is correct, but it will also exclude commons-io:2.4, and in my case I needed that. So you can exclude by specific group:

```
compile('YOUR_DEPENDENCY') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
```

This will only exclude version 1.3.2 from org.apache.commons, and will mantain commons.io:commons.io:2.4